# TypeError: sample_chain() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seed' - Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: typeerror, tensorflow2.0, macos-high-sierra, mcmc

Error with Tensorflow 2.0 using MCMC on MacOS 10.13.6

**The error on the console:**

```
2020-12-27 22:06:48.253835: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL-DNN to use the following CPU instructions in performance critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
To enable them in non-MKL-DNN operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-12-27 22:06:48.254353: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:115] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 4. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
objc[69111]: Class zmAppHelper is implemented in both /Library/ScriptingAdditions/zOLPluginInjection.osax/Contents/MacOS/zOLPluginInjection (0x1a48eaf4f0) and /Library/Application Support/Microsoft/ZoomOutlookPlugin/zOutlookPlugin64.bundle/Contents/MacOS/zOutlookPlugin64 (0x1a490e0518). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[69111]: class `ERCalendarEventEditorWindowController' not linked into application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dc7.py", line 131, in <module>
    chains, kernel_results = run_chain(initial_state)
  File "/Users/ram/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 457, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/ram/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 503, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
  File "/Users/ram/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 408, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/ram/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1848, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/ram/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2150, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/ram/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2041, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/Users/ram/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 915, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/ram/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py", line 358, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/ram/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 905, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in converted code:

    dc7.py:117 run_chain  *
        return tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(

    **TypeError: sample_chain() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seed'**
```

**Versions**

```
MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra

tensorflow                2.0.0           mkl_py37hda344b4_0  
tensorflow-base           2.0.0           mkl_py37h66b1bf0_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.0.0              pyh2649769_0  
tensorflow-probability    0.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0  
jupyter_core              4.7.0            py37hecd8cb5_0  
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0  
ipython                   7.19.0           py37h01d92e1_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
python                    3.7.9                h26836e1_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
```

**The source-code:**

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK'] = 'True'

from pprint import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

#import tensorflow as tf
#print(tf.__version__)

import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
tf.enable_v2_behavior()

import tensorflow_probability as tfp

sns.reset_defaults()
sns.set_context(context = 'talk', font_scale = 0.7)
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'viridis'

#%matplotlib inline

tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors


#### ============================================

#@title Utils { display-mode: "form" }
def print_subclasses_from_module(module, base_class, maxwidth=80):
  import functools, inspect, sys
  subclasses = [name for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module)
                if inspect.isclass(obj) and issubclass(obj, base_class)]
  def red(acc, x):
    if not acc or len(acc[-1]) + len(x) + 2 > maxwidth:
      acc.append(x)
    else:
      acc[-1] += ", " + x
    return acc
  print('\n'.join(functools.reduce(red, subclasses, [])))

# Generate some data
def f(x, w):
  # Pad x with 1's so we can add bias via matmul
  x = tf.pad(x, [[1, 0], [0, 0]], constant_values=1)
  linop = tf.linalg.LinearOperatorFullMatrix(w[..., np.newaxis])
  result = linop.matmul(x, adjoint=True)
  return result[..., 0, :]

num_features = 2
num_examples = 50
noise_scale = .5
true_w = np.array([-1., 2., 3.])

xs = np.random.uniform(-1., 1., [num_features, num_examples])
ys = f(xs, true_w) + np.random.normal(0., noise_scale, size=num_examples)

# Visualize the data set
plt.scatter(*xs, c=ys, s=100, linewidths=0)

grid = np.meshgrid(*([np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)] * 2))
xs_grid = np.stack(grid, axis=0)
fs_grid = f(xs_grid.reshape([num_features, -1]), true_w)
fs_grid = np.reshape(fs_grid, [100, 100])
plt.colorbar()
plt.contour(xs_grid[0, ...], xs_grid[1, ...], fs_grid, 20, linewidths=1)
plt.show()

### Sampling the noise scale

# Define the joint_log_prob function, and our unnormalized posterior.
def joint_log_prob(w, sigma, x, y):
  # Our model in maths is
  #   w ~ MVN([0, 0, 0], diag([1, 1, 1]))
  #   y_i ~ Normal(w @ x_i, noise_scale),  i=1..N

  rv_w = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(
    loc=np.zeros(num_features + 1),
    scale_diag=np.ones(num_features + 1))
  
  rv_sigma = tfd.LogNormal(np.float64(1.), np.float64(5.))

  rv_y = tfd.Normal(f(x, w), sigma[..., np.newaxis])
  return (rv_w.log_prob(w) +
          rv_sigma.log_prob(sigma) +
          tf.reduce_sum(rv_y.log_prob(y), axis=-1))

# Create our unnormalized target density by currying x and y from the joint.
def unnormalized_posterior(w, sigma):
  return joint_log_prob(w, sigma, xs, ys)


# Create an HMC TransitionKernel
hmc_kernel = tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
  target_log_prob_fn=unnormalized_posterior,
  step_size=np.float64(.1),
  num_leapfrog_steps=4)



# Create a TransformedTransitionKernl
transformed_kernel = tfp.mcmc.TransformedTransitionKernel(
    inner_kernel=hmc_kernel,
    bijector=[tfb.Identity(),    # w
              tfb.Invert(tfb.Softplus())])   # sigma


# Apply a simple step size adaptation during burnin
@tf.function
def run_chain(initial_state, num_results=1000, num_burnin_steps=500):
  adaptive_kernel = tfp.mcmc.SimpleStepSizeAdaptation(
      transformed_kernel,
      num_adaptation_steps=int(.8 * num_burnin_steps),
      target_accept_prob=np.float64(.75))

  return tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
    num_results=num_results,
    num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
    current_state=initial_state,
    kernel=adaptive_kernel,
    seed=(0, 1),
    trace_fn=lambda cs, kr: kr)


# Instead of a single set of initial w's, we create a batch of 8.
num_chains = 8
initial_state = [np.zeros([num_chains, num_features + 1]),
                 .54 * np.ones([num_chains], dtype=np.float64)]

chains, kernel_results = run_chain(initial_state)

r_hat = tfp.mcmc.potential_scale_reduction(chains)
print("Acceptance rate:", kernel_results.inner_results.inner_results.is_accepted.numpy().mean())
print("R-hat diagnostic (per w variable):", r_hat[0].numpy())
print("R-hat diagnostic (sigma):", r_hat[1].numpy())

w_chains, sigma_chains = chains
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using incompatible versions of tensorflow and tensorflow_probability.
With the following versions, the above Typererror went away:
ipython                   7.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.9                h26836e1_0
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-probability    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi